# Easily Type Esperanto ^ characters using x convention on iPhone

Tags: ios, keyboard, language, unicode

As some of you may know, Esperanto has several characters that have diacritics: ĉ, ĝ, ĥ, ĵ, ŝ, and ŭ.  None of these characters are available in the standard iOS 13.6 keyboard (what I am using currently).  The two workarounds that are sometimes used in such situations are the h-convention (so read "ch" as "ĉ", etc.) and the x-convention (so read "cx" as "ĉ", etc.). [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitutions_and_reforms_of_the_Esperanto_alphabet)

I do rather prefer to use the letters with diacritics than the h or x conventions.  My current workaround as a beginner has been: whenever I learn a new word that has a diacritic, I add a keyboard shortcut from the x-convention spelling to the standard spelling.  So now I have many keyboard shortcuts: mangxas -> manĝas (eats), cxambro -> ĉambro (room), etc.  This way whenever I type the x convention, I get the correct letter after all.  It really helps not to have to switch keyboards or otherwise fiddle with many steps to write each diacritic letter, especially for learning a language through duolingo where exercises switch back and forth in terms of which input language they require, and some of those exercises are timed.

While this works well-enough when I am learning 1-2 words/day, it does take additional time that I feel is not optimally spent.  It also is likely unsustainable for at least two reasons: (A) my vocabulary acquisition is being slowed by how quickly I can add words to what is ultimately a full dictionary that I am writing, and more importantly (B) Esperanto is a highly inflected and agglutinative language.  So when I learned that "manĝas" is a verb meaning "eats", I also (eventually) learn "manĝis" "eaten", "manĝos" "will eat", "manĝi" "to eat", "manĝu" "eat!". And then there are the the endings for adjectives "manĝa" ("food"); nouns "manĝo" ("food"), both of which have plural ("manĝaj", "manĝoj") and object ("manĝan", "manĝon") and plural-object forms ("manĝajn", "manĝojn"), and several dozen different suffixes, infixes, and compound words such as "manĝulo" ("eater"/"foodie"), "matenmanĝo" (breakfast), which themselves have their own verb/adjective/plural/object forms....

While just having "mangx"->"manĝ" would have some additional utility, it would force me into a "type root, press space, delete space, add ending" pattern of inefficiency without covering the cases of compound words, nor allowing easy input of the several infixes/suffixes that themselves have diacritic letters.  For example, to type the verb "to blush" "ruĝiĝi" (from "ruĝ" "red" + "iĝi" "to become"), would involve typing "r u g x [space] i g x [space] [delete] [left-left] [delete] [right-right] i [space]", rather than just "r u g x i g x i [space]", which seems simple enough to me.

So I have three questions to ask of iOS:

1. Is it possible for keyboard shortcuts (or assigning hot keys, or other typing method) to apply WITHIN words, rather than requiring a space to activate them?  If I could just get "gx"->"ĝ" all the time, without typing a space before or after, that would be ideal.
2. Is it possible to download/import a collection of keyboard shortcuts directly into my phone, rather than input each manually?  It would not take too much coding to automate the creation a full dictionary of shortcuts that cover the vast majority of use cases.  It would save me the time of manually entering them all, and still allow me to keep my "gx"->"ĝ" etc. method of input.
3. If there is no reliable way to just get iOS to recognize that when I type "gx" I always want "ĝ" etc., is there any method of getting these diacritic letters easily accessible by adding them to the options for accented letters that pop up when I hold down c/g/h/j/s/u?  Currently none are available by this method.  (If this involves switching the keyboard I am fine so long as it stays a QWERTY or DVORAK layout.)

I am open to other ideas, if the above are all untenable.  Clearly I am not the first person to type Esperanto in iOS.  I would like to not have to learn a new layout, and I do want the diacritic letters to be as easily typed as possible, because they are not rare.

TL;DR:  Is there anyway in iOS 13.6 to get "gx"->"ĝ" in the middle of words when typing?

Comment: Have you tried the esperanto keyboard available in the app store.?  Also the Keyman app may have one.

Comment: This is may help - free Esperanto keyboard for ios: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/esperanto-klavaro-keyboard/id951119795 ...

Comment: Thank you for these responses.  When I try to load that app, I get an error message that it is not available in my area.  I have tried both the Esperanto keyboard by le sang, and the one available on keyman.  I do think they answer my #3 above adequately, but if anyone has more information regarding #1 or #2 those would be my preference.

Comment: #1 is not possible to my knowledge.